# Most efficient way to initialize class member vector with large data set

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the fastest/memory efficient way to initialize **with data** a `std::vector` member variable in a class?

Here is what I was able to come up with:

```
class LargeClass
{
//lot of data, with long running constructor to initialize them 
}

class EngineClass
{

public:
EngineClass( const vector<LargeClass>& vectorOfLargeClass )
{
mVectorOfLargeClass = vectorOfLargeClass; //Here is what I was able to come up
}

private:
vector<LargeClass> mVectorOfLargeClass;

}

int main()
{
vector<LargeClass> vectorOfLargeClass;
...
//fill vectorOfLargeClass with a lot of data
...
EngineClass engine( vectorOfLargeClass );
...
}
```

I need `EngineClass` to hold a copy of data of the `vectorOfLargeClass` vector which was created in `main()`.

I use C++11, but I am not fully familiar with the language, and maybe there is a better more standard way to do such task.

Comment: do you need to make a *copy* or can you *move* what you've already constructed?

Comment: I am actually interested in both the move and copy. Move is faster right?, than the copy stated above?

Comment: @Avithohol by definition, there is no copy if you *move*, so.. yeah. Nothing is infinitely faster than something =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do:

```
class EngineClass
{
public:
    EngineClass(vector<LargeClass> vectorOfLargeClass) :
        mVectorOfLargeClass(std::move(vectorOfLargeClass) {}

private:
    vector<LargeClass> mVectorOfLargeClass;
};
```

So you may move or copy your vector:

```
EngineClass engine( vectorOfLargeClass ); // copy
EngineClass engine(std::move(vectorOfLargeClass)); // move
```

Comment: what about **swap**? Would it be faster than **move**?

Comment: swap would be about the same as move because `std::swap` should move if it has the option

Comment: @Avithohol No, not noticibly.

Comment: thanks, lets talk about the constructor here:  **EngineClass(vector<LargeClass> vectorOfLargeClass) :** ... will this not create a fully fledged and needless copy of the vector, just to pass it to the std::move? Wouldn't be a **EngineClass(vector<LargeClass>& vectorOfLargeClass) :** better similarly like @marcinj did it?

Comment: @avith a vector is 3 pointers.  That is small and cheap.  The data is the expensive part.  Move-in to a value arg, and the cost evaporates.  Forget to move, and huge cost.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry I feel like a 3 yo, what do you mean by "Forget to move, and huge cost"? You mean this?: **EngineClass engine( vectorOfLargeClass );**

Comment: @avit yes.  Put `EngineClass engine( std::move(vectorOfLargeClass) );` to make it cheap.  Btw, use "backticks" to quote code inline, not bold double-stars.

Answer (score 6):

Add move constructor:

```
EngineClass( vector<LargeClass>&& vectorOfLargeClass ) :
    mVectorOfLargeClass(std::move(vectorOfLargeClass))
{
}
```

then use it as follows:

```
EngineClass engine( std::move(vectorOfLargeClass) );
```

but this assumes `vectorOfLargeClass` is after `std::move` no longer needed in `main`

Comment: Forcing a move-in is an interesting option, but one you should justify rather than just leave it there.

Comment: I don't get the double reference operator here ... does that mean the reference of the pointer is taken and passed to the std::move?

Comment: @Avith `&&` as a type modifier means "rvalue reference", or "reference to something you can treat as a temporary and steal its state by moving from it safely".  It is just a reference, but one that binds to temporaries in a writable eay, or from objects cast via `std::move` to look like a temporary.  Learn about moving and rvalues in C++11.

Comment: And the call would be `EngineClass engine( vector<LargeClass>(vectorOfLargeClass) );` in the copy case.

Comment: Actually I though of adding move constructor and leaving current OP's copy constructor as it is (maybe moving copy to ctor's initialization list). In the end this would result in the same code as the one from Jarod42 answer. So my solution might look rather low level.

Comment: @Avithohol - if you are after speed, then make sure LargeClass (which as You say is very large) implements properly move semantics and make its move constructor noexcept, otherwise vector will work slow when resizing (it will make copies instead of moves).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster way would be to use the constructor's initializer list to initialize your member variables:

```
EngineClass( const vector<LargeClass>& vectorOfLargeClass )
: mVectorOfLargeClass(vectorOfLargeClass)
{
}
```

Generally, prefer to initialize your member variables in the constructor's initializer list.

If you don't want to copy the input vector but rather transfer its element in the member vector you could use `std::vector::swap` member function which is super fast, since it is equivalent with pointer exchange, to swap the buffers between the vectors:

```
EngineClass( vector<LargeClass>& vectorOfLargeClass )
{
  mVectorOfLargeClass.swap(vectorOfLargeClass);
}
```

Comment: Why is this slightly faster?

Comment: @Jonas Is faster because you initialize the member vector upon its birth. Otherwise the vector's constructor is first called (i.e., the member vector is being created) and then you call the member assignment operator of the vector to copy the elements. This involves more functions calls which makes it a litle bit slower.

Comment: Good point. Could the compiler optimize the first constructor call out?

Comment: @Jonas I'm not a compiler writer but I doubt that the compiler would optimize something like that.

Comment: This is a horrible design.  If you are going to steal the state of an argument, don't just take it by `&`, this isn't C++03.

Comment: @Yakk so do you say, that instead of **EngineClass( vector<LargeClass>& vectorOfLargeClass )** the following **EngineClass( vector<LargeClass> vectorOfLargeClass )**would be better? Or double reference operator like marcinj did?

Comment: @avith the price of an extra vector move is tiny.  `&&` is only useful here if you want to make copies harder.  By value is basically as efficient, and makes copies easier.  I can see a good case for either, and none for `&` or `const&`.